# Exeception in application when Threading used to saveImage simultaneously from multiple IP Camera

Tags: c++, exception, opencv, mfc

I am working on application where I connect the application and display multiple video feed from IP cameras. I am able to get the video feed which is too laggy(working to get solution to remove the lag). And in the application I have Button which when clicked it takes 50 pictures from all the IP cameras connected. But the code I have implemented gives an exception when threading is implemented. When used without threading it works fine.Heres the code for the Button Event.

```
void CDialogBasedVideoDlg::OnBnClickedButtonTakePic()
{
int nIndex = m_CamListBox.GetCurSel();
CStaticEx *objStaticEx = (CStaticEx*)m_StaticArray.GetAt(nIndex);
objStaticEx->StartThreadToCaptureUSBCam();//threading implementation gives exception.
//objStaticEx->CapturePicture();//this func works fine(without threading)
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

I have overrriden Static class which dynamically creates a picture control and displays the live video feed, threading is implemented in this class where the images are saved. Here's the code for capturing images and threading function.

```
void CStaticEx::CapturePicture(void)
{
CString csFileDir;
CString csFileName;

csFileDir.Format(DIR_USB_CAM_NAME,m_IpAddr);
if(IsDirExist(csFileDir)== false){
    CreateDirectory(csFileDir, NULL);       
}
CString csStr = csFileDir;
csStr += RANDOM_FILE_SEARCH;
int nNoOfFile = CountFileNumInDir((char*)csStr.GetBuffer());
csFileDir += DBL_SLASH;

int i = 0;
do{
    csFileName.Format(FILE_NAME, csFileDir, (m_nCamID+1));
    CString csCount;
    csCount.Format(_T("%d"),(nNoOfFile+1));
    csFileName += csCount;
    csFileName += JPG;
    m_pFrameImg = cvQueryFrame( m_pCamera ); //<----Exception come at this point 
    if(m_pFrameImg){
        cvSaveImage(csFileName, m_pFrameImg);
        i++;
        nNoOfFile++;
        csFileName = _T("");
    }
}while(i < 50);
 }
```

Threading Control function.

```
  void CStaticEx::StartThreadToCaptureUSBCam(){
THREADSTRUCT *_param = new THREADSTRUCT;
_param->_this = this;
AfxBeginThread(StartThread,_param);


 }

 UINT CStaticEx::StartThread (LPVOID param)
 {
THREADSTRUCT*   ts = (THREADSTRUCT*)param;
//AfxMessageBox("Thread Started");
ts->_this->CapturePicture();
return 1;
 }
```

Exception thrown is as follows.

```
Windows has treggered a breakpoint in DialogBasedVideo.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of heap, which indicates a bug in DialogBasedVideo.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while dialogbasedvideo.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information. How do i get rid of this exception.
```

All the experts out their please help me.I am using VS2010 and Windows7, OpenCv2.4.6 Thanks in advance.